# How to reduce OOM score for X11 with systemd

Tags: systemd, xorg, out-of-memory

When my PC runs out of memory, the Linux OOM killer likes to kill Xorg first rather than the actual app using a lot of memory, which for the most part takes down the whole system (killing all my apps instead of just the one with the bad memory leak.)

It is my understanding that I can avoid this by setting the OOM-killer score for X11 to a very low value, such as `-900`, so that the kernel OOM killer will try to end other tasks first, making it much more likely to kill a bad application instead of the whole windowing environment.

However I can't see how to do this with `systemd`.  Apparently there is an [OOMScoreAdjust](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#OOMScoreAdjust=) option you can set in a `.service` file, except 1) I thought I shouldn't be editing these system-owned files directly (as they'll get overwritten during an upgrade) and 2) I can't even find the one for X-Windows.  I only have a `display-manager.service` which points to `lightdm`.

How might one tell `systemd` to adjust the OOM score for Xorg?  I am using Arch Linux, although I believe they don't make many/any changes to `systemd`.

Comment: "I thought I shouldn't be editing these system-owned files directly (as they'll get overwritten during an upgrade)" ... which is why you have [`systemd edit`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Editing_provided_units), which will create a override file in `/etc` which will be unaffected by package upgrades. That said, there won't be a service for X, since it is started and managed  by your display manager, which seems to be LightDM.

Comment: Aha, didn't know about that, thanks!  Assume you mean `systemctl edit`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, `systemctl edit`.

Comment: Have you considered adding more swap?

Comment: I haven't, because it will just delay the inevitable.  It's usually only one or two programs that gradually chew through memory, and after a week or so they are sometimes using 90%+ of the total RAM.  Adding more swap will just postpone the problem for a couple more days, so I'd rather tackle it by ensuring that when it does happen, it just kills the process leaking the memory instead of bringing the whole system down!

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can manually adjust the score by echoing the value into `/proc/[pid]/oom_score_adj` for a given process, see `man 5 proc`.

Comment: @meuh: Yep I do this to adjust the score of apps I load, by echoing into `/proc/self/oom_score_adj` then `exec`ing the process (e.g. web browser) however I'm looking for an automated way to do it.  systemd does have a way to look after it for you so that seems like the way to go since X is being started by systemd, but I can't see how to apply it to the X server.

Comment: systemd won't start X. it will start a display manager: gdm, kdm, lightdm, ... . This one in turn will start X. So the change should be done in the display manager related config. For example in lightdm.conf there's this handy (commented) entry called `xserver-command =` .  put a wrapper to Xorg (or to Xorg's own wrapper...) there

Answer (score 0):

This is a preliminary answer, I will update it as more detail comes to hand.

`systemd` does not launch X like the old runlevel system used to, but rather it launches the display manager (LightDM in my case) and it's actually the display manager that starts X.

So the question is really how one tells the display manager to alter the OOM score of the X server.

I asked a question of the LightDM developers and they seem open to the idea of including an option to set the OOM score (as having the parent process set the OOM score seems to be the better way of doing so), so it will be a matter of someone implementing that option.

Until then, the suggestion in the above comments of altering the `xserver-command` config option should do the trick.